# Conky $mem/$memmax RAM report differs from free -m command

Tags: command-line, ram, conky

I have this Conky report on my desktop screen:

[image]

This is a relevant part of the `conky.conf` file:

```
${color1}${font ConkySymbols:size=16}J${font} ${voffset -10}Memory» $hr${color}
${color1}${goto 35}RAM : ${color}$mem/$memmax ${alignr}$memperc% ${membar 4,100}
${color1}${goto 35}SWAP: ${color}$swap/$swapmax $alignr}$swapperc% ${swapbar 4,100}
```

However when I run `free -m` I get this:

[image]

Which is 2GB less than the Conky's report (6GB vs 8.3GB).

I also tried running the `mem` command in terminal, but the command is not recognized.

How to run in the terminal the command that Conky uses to find used/free RAM stats and why is there a difference with the `free -m` command?

**EDIT**:

```
${color1}${goto 35}RAM: ${execi 10 free --si -m|awk '/^Mem/{printf "%.2f",$3/1024}'}/$memmax ${execi 10 free --si -m|awk '/^Mem/{printf "%.1f%%", 100*$3/$2}'} \
${execibar 10 free --si -m|awk '/^Mem/{print 100*$3/$2}'}
```

[image]

Comment: I might be off base here but it looks as though Conky is adding the used and shared together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [sources](https://github.com/brndnmtthws/conky/blob/master/src/linux.cc#L258) it seems that `info.mem` is calculated as `info.memmax - memavail` where these are read from `/proc/meminfo` in fields:

```C
    if (strncmp(buf, "MemTotal:", 9) == 0) {
      sscanf(buf, "%*s %llu", &info.memmax);
...
    } else if (strncmp(buf, "MemAvailable:", 13) 
      sscanf(buf, "%*s %llu", &memavail);
```

---

To call `free` from conky you can use, for example,

```
RAM: ${execi 10 free --si -m|awk '/^Mem/{printf "%.2fGiB\n",$3/1024}'}/$memmax   \
${execi 10 free --si -m|awk '/^Mem/{printf "%.1f%%\n", 100*$3/$2}'} \
${execibar 10 free --si -m|awk '/^Mem/{print 100*$3/$2}'}
```

but the size of the bar generated by `execibar` is fixed by global variables you have to set in the `conky.config` part with:

```
default_bar_height = 4,
default_bar_width = 100,
```

The output of `free` is is passed to `awk` which looks for the line beginning `Mem` and takes the 3rd (`$3`) word on the line and reformats it (see `man sprintf`). You can set the number of decimal places in the format `%.2f` by changing the number 2.

Comment: Is there some other `$` command that I can use inside `conky.conf` for it to display correct memory usage?

Comment: The definition of "correct" is ambiguous. Conky gives a useful value that also includes memory used to implement tmpfs filesystems (such as `/tmp`). If you want to, you can use the output of `free -m`. I'll add an example to my answer.

Comment: Could you please show how I need to change the conky `RAM` line? I tried to use your code, but it didn't work correctly (see last edit on the question)

Comment: I found the error (extra `$`). I replaced `10` with `2`- it's the renewal rate, right? How would I get it to display 2 decimal points though? eg `3.42` instead of `3.4`? And what is the `|awk '/^Mem/{print $3}'` part responsible for?

Comment: And I'm not sure how to update the ram percentage bar

Comment: What I have right now is this:


`${color1}${goto 35}RAM : ${color}${execi    2 free --si -h|awk '/^Mem/{print $3}'}/$memmax`

and 

`${alignr}$memperc% ${membar 4,100}`

Comment: I've updated the answer to give something closer to the original conky output and address some of your points.

Comment: Unfortunatelly the percentage bar looks off ;((( (compared to the bar in SWAP). Have I missed something (my code in EDIT)

Comment: As I mentioned, you can only change the size of that bar in the `conky.config={}` section.

Comment: I added those, but it is not right-aligned,  the way the SWAP's bar is... And I tried removing all `/n` the big gap between the RAM and SWAP persists too\

Comment: I suppose it's because I removed `GiB` from used memory. Is there a way to just add three spaces before the RAM bar?

Comment: You can align any following items to the right by preceding them with `${alignr}` which exists in other parts of your example. Please open a new post for any new problems so that others may answer.

Comment: Alright. Thank you a lot for your help!